# Run a recurring background job every 28DAYS IN RESPECTIVE of the month

Tags: .net, hangfire

I am building an application where i want a background job to be fired every 28 Days. My current implementation calculates 28 days based on the current month.

ReccuringJOb.AddorUPdate(()=>methodcall, "0 20 */28 **").
This  job runs every 28 days of the month at 8pm. But what i rather want to achieve is if for example a user creates an account today with datejoined as DAtetime.now,The recurring job should calculate 28Days based on  datejoined and not 28 days based on the current month.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Cron.DayInterval(interval)**

For Example

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("MyJob",() => ScheduledJob(), Cron.DayInterval(28));
```

Comment: still same issue. i want the job to execute every 28 days in respective of the month. your current implementation currently runs on the 28th day of every month

Comment: DayInterval(28) will schedule a recurring job with frequency of every 28 days. DayInterval(28) will return the CronExpression "* * */28 * *". You can read Slash section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression to learn more about how expression works

Comment: thats exactly my point. what i want to achieve is this. assuming you have a job that needs to run every 28Days and the job starts running on march 25th, 2018, the 28 days should start counting from that exact date. Your current implementation which i already have with same issue will run the job on the 28th of every month meaning this job would kick off in 3 days time which is not what i want. the job should rather run on the 24th of April 2018